# R Two matrices, extract rows from m based on common column of r

Tags: r, matrix, extract

My question is about matrixes for R. I have two matrices r and m:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
15 56 44 1 4 7
61 31 63 7 1 3
10 36 99 5 9 6
65 79 88 54 1 1"))
colnames(m) <- c("Z","Q","A","F","D","H")

r <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
15 56 64   
10 36 61 "))
colnames(r) <- c("Z","L","O")
```

I want to extract the rows based on common column (in this case Z column), so the result would be

```
A

15 56 44 1 4 7

10 36 99 5 9 6
```

A is the new matrix.

Any Ideas how to ?

Comment: Did you try `merge(m,r)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
> merge(x=m, y=r, by='Z')
   Z  Q  A F D H  L  O
1 10 36 99 5 9 6 36 61
2 15 56 44 1 4 7 56 64
```

To only keep the columns in `m`:

```
> merge(x=r, y=m, by='Z', sort=FALSE)[colnames(m)]
   Z  Q  A F D H
1 15 56 44 1 4 7
2 10 36 99 5 9 6
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I used the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
 indx <- intersect(colnames(m), colnames(r))
 m[m[,indx] %in% r[,indx],]
 #    Z  Q  A F D H
 #[1,] 15 56 44 1 4 7
 #[2,] 10 36 99 5 9 6
```